# Can xsd parent element (base) be given default value in child (extension/restriction)?

Tags: xsd

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="tSomeComponent">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="table" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="key" type="tKey" />
  <xs:element name="class" type="xs:string" />
 </xs:sequence>        
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="tStation">
 <xs:complexContent>
  <xs:restriction base="tSomeComponent">
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="table" type="xs:string" default="station" />
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I know that table default value in child should be done by restriction but i want to extend and restrict at same time. I know that this can be solved by adding more types but that's an overkill.

Comment: Why would adding more types be overkill, considering that you can declare them locally?   Adding another type that restricts xs:string is probably the right thing to do here.

Comment: Thanks. Can you make a short example as an answer. Would appreciate it.

Comment: By overkill i meant there would be 3rd type without table and then both tSomeComponent and tStation would extend it with table. Latter having default="station". That I consider overkill.